# Datetime formatted to string puts double slash 1/09//2014 instead of 15/09/2014

Tags: c#, string, datetime, format

I am converting with this format.

```
string dateA = dateA.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

When I am working local it works fine, but the its hosted in the server online it responds that way.

Other dates are working in the server, is just this case.

Comment: Is it just the double slash issue? Or is it actually showing a different date (as your title suggests)? In other words, is it giving you the 15th of September locally and the 1st of September (or maybe the 9th of January) on the server?

Comment: Apparently its cutting out the 15, into a 1.

But it is a 15.

Comment: When you say "other dates are working in the server", do you mean it's only this particular format string (so if you did `.ToString("dd-mm-yyyy")` it would work)? or it's only this particular date (15th of September)?

Comment: .ToString("dd-mm-yyyy").Replace("//","/")